# Can the tab selection indicator of TabLayout be pinned to the top of the screen while scrolling?

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library, android-coordinatorlayout, android-tablayout

I am investigating the way to pin the tab indicator of `TabLayout` in `CoordinatorLayout` while scrolling down.

If I add `scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed` flag to the `TabLayout`, then the tablayout itself is dissappeared while scrolling down. I want tab indicator bar be pinned to the top of the screen.

Is there a way to implement this?

[image]

Comment: Set minHeight of the CollapsingToolbarLayout to height of the indicator (4dp for example) and make sure exitUntilCollapsed is in its layout_scrollFlags property.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just have no flags at all. Your layout should be something like:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>

        <Toolbar app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
        <TabLayout/>

    </AppBarLayout>

    < /> <!-- ViewPager or other stuff -->
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

If you assign the `scroll` flag to the `TabLayout` it will start reacting to scroll gestures and will move/enter/exit according to your flags. As far as I understand about your question, you *don't* want it to move, so just remove the flags.

See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.html#SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL) for reference.

Comment: I want the tablayout to move out except the indicator bar on the bottom of tablayout.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide your custom `Behavior` for your `TabLayout` or `AppBarLayout` (only if `TabLayout` is only child of the `AppBarLayout`), where you will translate the y of the `TabLayout` to the `-mTabLayout.getHeight() + mTabIndicatorHeight`. You should do the same if you go with offseting top and bottom.

Currently, `TabLayout` does not have `@DefaultBehavior` and it is translated by the `AppBarLayout` behavior. Which is plain top and bottom offseting to the total amount of scroll range (sum of heights of views that have scrolling flags).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, I can't get it perfectly. Sorry. Could you give me more hints?